# How to convert val(sex) from javascript to php select option male or female

Tags: javascript, php

How to convert val(sex) from javascript to php select option male or female

```html
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#edit_gv').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var id    = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
            var name = $(e.relatedTarget).data('name');
            var sex = $(e.relatedTarget).data('sex');
           
            //Can pass as many onpage values or information to modal
            //Pass value to text
            $('#edit_MSCB').val(MSCB);
            $('#edit_Ten_GV').val(Ten_GV);
            
               $('#edit_sex').val(sex);`enter code here`
            //pass value to hrml
              $('#edit_sex').html(sex);
         });
    });

</script>

<select name="edit_sex"  id ="edit_sex" class="form-control">
      <option value ="0">male</option>
      <option value ="1">female</option>
</select>
```

How to convert val(sex) from javascript to php select option male or female..
thanks

Comment: Where is `'#edit_sex'`? Just submit the form?

Comment: #edit_sex in modal boostrap.form edit.

Comment: <div class="form-group row">
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
              <label class="control-label" for="edit_sex">sex:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="edit_sex"  class="form-control" id="edit_sex">
                  <option value ="0">Male</option>
                  <option value ="1">Female</option>
                </select>
              </div>
          </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sexval = $('#sex').val();
```

you can use above code and get get value

```
var sex = (sexval == 1)?'female':'male';
```

Comment: please,you can give example? I new member.

Comment: you just take the value using $('#sex').val();. Then just pass that value to php and verify its male or female OR you can verify in javascript and pass value to PHP server using var sex = (sexval == 1)?'female':'male';

Comment: Or `var sex = ['female','male'][sexval]`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @Anish pointed out associate ids to your selection boxes, but if your server just puts the values sent from the Client in your user table or whatever I can put values like `Käsekuchen` in there.

```
1. Press F12
2. Click on "Inspector"
3. Search for your checkbox
4. Edit ID of Male
5. Select Male
6. Now send "Käsekuchen" to the Server or anything else.
```

So have a server side script that checks if the values are correct and then you're safe. (Not-really)